# Get unique keys from multiple objects

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of objects like this:

```
var mountains = [
    { name: 'Kebnekaise', elevation: 2106 },
    { name: 'Mount Ngauruhoe', elevation: 2291, comment: 'aka Mount Doom' }
];
```

How to get all unique keys i.e. `['name', 'elevation', 'comment']`?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you sure its performance is a problem? How often are you doing this that it has to be the **most** performant way?

Comment: "*Most performant*" is too broad and depends on specific cases. Fix your question.

Comment: I would simply loop through the array, then loop through the keys of the object, and add them as keys to a result object. Then use `Object.keys(result)` to get the list of unique keys.

Comment: Changed the question to not include the performance part. Better?

Comment: Yes, better. BTW there are quite a few versions of this question using underscore.

Comment: I mostly added the question because I thought there would be a better way of doing this then what I came up with and that I was surprise to not find anything when searching for it. We are not using underscore, but can you link to one of those questions?

Comment: @Amit I like your ES2015 answer better than I could like any Underscore answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ECMAScript 2015, it's really simple:

```
let mountains = [
  { name: 'Kebnekaise', elevation: 2106 },
  { name: 'Mount Ngauruhoe', elevation: 2291, comment: 'aka Mount Doom' }
];

let uniqueKeys = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...mountains));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ES6, one could do

```
var unique = new Set([].concat.apply([],mountains.map(Object.keys)))
```

Without ES6, something like

```
var unique = [].concat.apply([],mountains.map(Object.keys)).filter(function(value,i,arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(value) === i;
});
```

Comment: @Amit - I'm guessing it was because yours is neater, but getting an array of all keys and creating a Set from them, still works fine, it's just a little longer and not as readable as using a spread and Object.assign

Comment: I really hope whoever down voted had a better reason. An answer isn't good or bad as a function of other answers.

Comment: Also wonder why it got a downvote. Great to see a minimal none es6 solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the array of objects and iterate over each element's keys with `Object.keys(obj)`, adding them to a hash to avoid duplicates:

```
function getKeySet (data) {
  var keys = {};

  data.forEach(function (datum) {
    Object.keys(datum).forEach(function (key) {
      keys[key] = true;
    });
  });

  return Object.keys(keys);
}
```

Alternately you could add all the keys to an array and filter out duplicates. Either way this will be O(nm) where n is the number of elements in the array and m is the average number of keys.